# Command 'vue' not found, did you mean: command 'vpe' from deb texlive-latex-extra Try: sudo apt install <deb name> on UBUNTU

Tags: javascript, vue.js, command-line, vue-cli-3

I'm trying to setup vue js on my system, I've installed the necessary things such as npm, yarn etc and vue-cli itself but when I try creating a vue folder using vue init webpack-simple myapp it returns the following error: Command 'vue' not found, did you mean:

command 'vpe' from deb texlive-latex-extra

Try: sudo apt install

Comment: Are you sure vue-cli is installed globally?  Also the new vue-cli doesn't use init, it's `vue create` or `vue ui`.

Comment: Yes, vue-cli is installed globally, vue create and vue ui returns the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HIS FIXED THE ISSUE FOR ME:

After running

sudo npm install -g @vue/cli

I ran

sudo nano $HOME/.profile

and pasted the following line

export PATH=$PATH:/home/chike/.npm-global/bin

after writing the code, next thing I did was Ctrl + O, ENTER and Ctrl + X then wrote

vue init webpack myapp

Comment: Instead of /home/username/.npm-global/bin you can use $HOME/.npm-global/bin. If you installed vue cli using yarn you should add this path instead $HOME/.yarn/bin

Answer (score 2):

For me `sudo` helps to solve it. Try to use this command in terminal without any additional commands, just:

`sudo yarn global add @vue/cli`

Then you can check the version and all will work correctly.

`vue --version`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to install Vue CLI use one of those commands:

npm:

```
npm install -g @vue/cli
```

yarn:

```
yarn global add @vue/cli
```